# How can I specify my experience after transitioning from full time to part time for the same firm?

Tags: career-development

I worked as a full time software developer for a firm. Later on after two years I started working part time for the same firm and doing the same work I was doing before.

I am confused about how to describe this. Should I consider this as two separate experiences or just one?

Comment: I think it depends on the level of detail you wish to have in your CV / resumé / LinkedIn profile.

Comment: I don't have any issues discussing the reasons. I just wanted to prepare for something , may be some competitive exam or some things(or may be for a change)

Answer (score 2):

> Should I consider this as two separate experiences or just one?

I would treat them as two separate experiences, rather than just one.

That way, if the interviewer learns that you went from full to part-time, it won't appear as if you had been trying to hide something.

It might looks something like this:

**Company A**, City Z

Software Developer (part time)                            2011-2013

...

Software Developer                                        2009-2011

...

Comment: Although, if you're doing the same work, I'd only list that once, below the two entries for Software Developer, within the one section for that company.